# Trend Micro deepsecurity delete a computer: HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request

Tags: python-3.x, api, rest, deepsecurity

Trying to delete a computer from TMDS (Trend Micro Deep Security) with the python script provided.

The script was copied from TMDS and slightly altered. I added a line where the document which opens also is being read.

tmds_del_comp_list.txt => contains the computername to delete. eg: computername.domain.domain

creds.py contains the api_key.

The ipaddress and port has been changed for obvious reasons.

To confirm, the deepsecurity module has been installed in the same directory.

Directories deepsecurity, deep_security_api.egg-info, build and **pycache** are present.

```
# DEL operation, /api/computers/{computerID}

from __future__ import print_function
import sys, warnings
import deepsecurity
from deepsecurity.rest import ApiException
import creds

# Setup
if not sys.warnoptions:
        warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
configuration = deepsecurity.Configuration()
configuration.host = 'https://ipaddress:1234/api/computers/{computerID}'

# Authentication
configuration.api_key['api-secret-key'] = creds.api_key

# Initialization
# Set Any Required Values
# api_version = 'v4'
reed = open('tmds_del_comp_list.txt', mode='r' )
computer_id = reed.read()
api_instance = deepsecurity.ComputersApi(deepsecurity.ApiClient(configuration))
api_version = 'v1'

try:
        api_instance.delete_computer(computer_id, api_version)

except ApiException as e:
        print("An exception occurred when calling ComputersApi.delete_computer: %s\n" % e)
```

error received:

```
An exception occurred when calling ComputersApi.delete_computer: (400)
Reason:
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8', 'Content-Language': 'en', 'Content-Length': '435', 'Date': 'Thu, 06 Oct 2022 09:24:22 GMT', 'Connection': 'close'})
HTTP response body: <!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</title><style type="text/css">body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</h1></body></html>
```

Before this error i received different errors, which i corrected. I had a .env file instead of creds.py.
I have tested out if my tmds_del_comp_list.txt file was actually being read, it was not so that's why i added the line with the read function. ( when i did print `print(reed)` nothing came up)
The api_version was wrong, from the documentation i understood that TMDS version 20 corresponds to version v4 in the API. After changing it to v1, no more error. When double checking the version in the browser `https://ipaddress:4119/rest/apiVersion` I get 4. Bit baffled by this.

`'https://ipaddress:1234/api/computers/{computerID}'`

I find the url weird. The {computerID} bit is what i find weird since it does not correspond to any variable. I do not see how it works together with the rest of the code, unless api_instance.delete_computer adds computer_id to {computerID}. There's no indication that what i think is correct or not.

`api_instance.delete_computer(computer_id, api_version)`

Googling does not really bring any relevant information up.
I'm a beginner with python, api's and deepsecurity.
Any leads, pointing to the obvious and constructive help/comments/etc are very welcome.

Edit1: looking back at all the docs available, i see that "computerID" should be an integer, which in our organisation, it is not a number or integer but a vm name + domain name.
Maybe there's a number connected to every VM reporting to TMDS. Maybe i'll try to Get/List all computers to see what id's they have.
I did try that and i could not find an ID number with just a number.
This is probably not the issue.

```
path Parameters
computerID
required
    
integer <int32> \d+

The ID number of the computer to delete.
Example: 1
```

Edit2: When clicking on the arrow down next to GET/computers from link <https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/article/12_0/api-reference/tag/Computers#operation/listComputers>
I get to see this link `https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/#operation/searchComputers/computers` which points to the correct endpoint i presume and where #operation should be replaced by GET. When doing so i get a 404 response. I got a 404 when changing the endpoint to `/get/computers`.
Conclusion, end-point is probably correct, when it is not, i do get an error that the url is wrong.

error:

```
An exception occurred when calling ComputersApi.list_computers: (404)
Reason:
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1;mode=block', 'Set-Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=codewithlettersandnumbers; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax', 'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1', 'Content-Length': '105', 'Date': 'Thu, 06 Oct 2022 14:56:58 GMT'})
HTTP response body:

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=/SignIn.screen">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit3: Testing a simple GET/computers with Postman gave me a clue that the actual key was wrong. I corrected that and got a 200 response. So the key was wrong. I corrected that on my python script but i still get the same 400 error.

Comment: I'm not gonna edit my question anymore, its getting too long, i guess.
I discovered the help() function, does have deepsecurity information.
Just enter the python terminal.
`python3`
`help()`
`modules deepsecurity`

Funny how i could not find that before and now i had a moment of ow lets try that again and it suddenly works. I must've done something wrong before.

Comment: Just found out with Postman that each VM does have an integer ID number. So using the ID number of my VM name is the first change needed.

Comment: I found the ID number needed with Postman, same Post request with Python does not seem to work. Back on the Python train.

Comment: Very weird, i get a 404 wrong url with python, with postman i use exactly the same url where it works without a problem. I start to think there's something wrong with the setup although everything seems to be in order.

Comment: OK, the documentation does not specify a "?" to be used in the endpoint but it should be there [link](https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/article/20_0/api-reference/tag/Computers#operation/searchComputers) So the endpoint should be `/computers/search?`

Comment: Last comment for a while. I'll come back to the Python version of the script but for now i need to concentrate on the Ansible version with module uri. I hope to come and update this post with my fully functional Python script...